# Is it possible to remove a cached image at Appcelerator?

Tags: caching, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am building an Appcelerator app, which retrieves the profile image of a regular user, in this way:

```html
<ImageView id="profileImage" defaultImage="/images/default_profile.jpg"></ImageView>
```

And the controller gets the image from server (the url is unique for each user):

```js
$.profileImage.image = "myserver.com/profile/1/image"
```

The issue is that I update the profile image (sending a new one to the server), but the content is never refreshed because it uses the same url.

For example:
1) myserver.com/profile/1/image is an image "X"
2) I send a "Y" to the server
3) myserver.com/profile/1/image gets an image "X". Because it is cached by Appcelerator. But of course, I would like to get the "Y".

So is it possible to remove a cached image at Appcelerator?

Set a get param (such as "?date=now())") is not an answer here, because i have to get the profile image in different views, and I have to have this cached.

Thanks in advance.

Guille

Answer (score 3):

Remote Images in Titanium are always automatically cached based on their urls.

So, to make your task done, you have two ways to do it:

1. Change the url from the server (I know it's complicated and not very good approach).
2. Or use this function

   ```
   function clearCacheDirectory() {
       try {
         Ti.API.info("deleting cache...");
         var temp = Ti.Filesystem.getApplicationCacheDirectory();

         var cacheDir = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(temp);

         cacheDir.deleteDirectory(true);

      } catch(exc) {
       Ti.API.info("Cache error = " + exc);
      }
   }
   ```

   - Above function will delete all content of cache directory and it works on both iOS and Android
   - See [Ti.FileSystem here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem.File-method-deleteDirectory) it's all you need to solve your problem.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Prashant, your solution works perfectly.  I would only add that using your solution in a classic app, I simply dropped it into app.js.

Answer (score 0):

As Prashant Saini said, the only works for me was change the `url` each imageview is loaded, adding random storing to `url`, for example:

```
var randfake = new Date();    
$.userPhoto.image = /serverpath/images/?randfake='+randfake.getTime();
```